# How To Integrate FVM with an existing flutter project in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, fvm

I am working on two projects. one has flutter version of 2.10.1 and another has version 2.10.5. it is very irritating and difficult for me to download each time the version. I have already activated fvm but I am not able to manage the "fvm absolute path" in flutter sdk path. how can I have the .fvm/flutter_sdk directory in my running project to get "fvm absolute path"?

Answer (score 2):

**For Android Studio**

1. install flutter versions

```bash
$ fvm install 2.10.1
$ fvm install 2.10.5
```

You can list the versions which had been installed with command below:

```bash
$ fvm list             
Cache Directory:  /Users/xxx/fvm/versions

2.10.1
2.10.5
```

2. use fvm to change new version with command below:

```bash
$ cd project
$ fvm use 2.10.5 -f
```

3. change the Flutter SDK path in Android Studio Perferences.

You can select the version from Perferences. Search Flutter settings.
You must have install Flutter plugin, so change the setting `Flutter SDK path` to your version like this:
`xxx/project/.fvm/flutter_sdk`

your project have the folder `.fvm` after execute the command `fvm use 2.10.5 -f` before. specify the sdk path to your project `.fvm/flutter_sdk` absolute path

for more details to view offical website [fvm](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration/#android-studio).

**For vscode**

install the version you need and switch to the version

For exists project

```
$ cd project
$ fvm use 2.10.5 -f
```

the command `fvm use 2.10.5 -f` will create or update `.fvm/flutter_sdk` and `.fvm/flutter_config.json`. the `.fvm/flutter_sdk` sybolink is the version 2.10.5 your changed.

add the file to your project root
`.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": ".fvm/flutter_sdk",
  // Remove .fvm files from searche
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  },
  // Remove from file watching
  "files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  }
}
```

You can view this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76270797/8624456 for more details or official website [fvm](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration).

Answer (score 1):

To use fvm, first you have to install the fvm on your system. For this follow below official link and follow the steps for your OS
https://fvm.app/documentation/getting-started/installation

Now you have to define a file `.fvmrc` in your root project location (same level as `pubspec.yaml`)

Now from your project folder run below commands

```
dart pub global activate fvm

fvm install
```

If we have to use any other version of flutter, then use `fvm use x.x.x` command.

Now to make sure, fvm is considered, all flutter commands should be run with fvm. for e.g. instead of `flutter run` it should now be `fvm flutter run`

At last, make sure your Android Studio settings are update to point to the fvm version of flutter sdk.

for e.g.

```
<your full project folder path>/.fvm/versions/3.19.1
```

This will make sure when you do pub get, it will behind the scene to fvm to perform the commands.

This will make sure your application level compileSDK version is compatible based on fvm managed flutter sdk and not the other default installed sdk on your machine.

Comment: thanks , your note to update the flutter sdk helps me .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `fvm install <VERSION>` in your project, by example : `fvm install 2.10.1`

You can check the version by using `fvm flutter --version`

All informations are in [FVM documentation](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration/#android-studio).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have **fvm** setup already, to add it to an existing project use  command **fvm use version **