# Use fvm to change flutter version in vscode, but the flutter version not work?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, fvm

I added [fvm](https://fvm.app/) to my project and set it up like [this](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration/). Now I can run all the commands for example `fvm use x.x.x` or `fvm flutter pub get`. Everything works.

BUT when running the application through VSCode directly (Play button or shortcut) it always uses my latest install SDK version. Why is it not starting with the *current flutter version* ?

This is my `settings.json`:

```
  {
  "dart.flutterSdkPaths": [
    "/Users/usr/fvm/versions"
  ],
    // Remove .fvm files from search
    "search.exclude": {
      "**/.fvm": true
    },
    // Remove from file watching
    "files.watcherExclude": {
      "**/.fvm": true
    }
  }
```

What am I missing here? How do I configure **fvm to work correctly with VSCode**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the `.fvm` folder set up properly? ie. It contains the symlink `flutter_sdk` (which points to the currently selected SDK) and the `fvm_config.json`.

In your `settings.json` file, you also need to set the location of the SDK itself:

```
"dart.flutterSdkPath": ".fvm/flutter_sdk",
```

Which will point to the same symlink.

Comment: How do we verify the symlink? The website says nothing about it, just that it exists. I have done this, and my `flutter doctor` still shows the global version, not the project version.

Answer (score 1):

General Apporch is below

For exists project
such as change version from 3.7.10 to 3.7.12

```
$ fvm install 3.7.12
$ cd project
$ fvm use 3.7.12 -f
```

with command `fvm use 3.7.12 -f`, the file `.fvm/fvm_config.json` will update and the sybolink `.fvm/flutter_sdk` also was updated to version 3.7.12.

```json
{
  "flutterSdkVersion": "3.7.10",
  "flavors": {}
}
```

to

```json
{
  "flutterSdkVersion": "3.7.12",
  "flavors": {}
}
```

`.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": ".fvm/flutter_sdk",
  // Remove .fvm files from search
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  },
  // Remove from file watching
  "files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  }
}
```

cd to you project and use `fvm use 3.7.12 -f` to change version.

For new project
To prevent compatibility issues with new version, may be create new project is best choice.

```bash
$ cd project
$ fvm use 3.7.12 -f
$ fvm flutter create --platforms=android --org com.xxx .
```

the command `fvm use 3.7.12 -f` will create `.fvm/flutter_sdk` and `.fvm/fvm_config.json` file.

add `.vscode/settings.json` to your project

Please read more detail with official website [fvm](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration#option-2---view-all-sdks-manual-switching)

The following answers are only for the above questions

You can list all installed local sdk versions first. such as:

```bash
$ fvm list
Cache Directory:  /Users/xxx/fvm/versions

3.10.0
3.7.12
```

1. edit below user xxx to your's

```json
{
    "dart.flutterSdkPaths": ["/Users/xxx/fvm/versions"],
    // Remove .fvm files from search
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/.fvm": true
    },
    // Remove from file watching
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.fvm": true
    }
}
```

2. Change Current Flutter SDK
   open vscode command palette, the shortcuts is

`Ctrl + Shift + p` for windows

`Cmd + Shift + p` for macOS

input command `Flutter: Change SDK` and select the command, this will be list all you have install sdks, select the one you wanted.

this will update the file `.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
    "dart.flutterSdkPaths": ["/Users/xxx/fvm/versions"],
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/xxx/fvm/versions/3.7.12", // this is your select new version
    // Remove .fvm files from search
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/.fvm": true
    },
    // Remove from file watching
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.fvm": true
    }
}
```

don't forget remove the folder `.fvm`, if you use this apporch.

```bash
$ rm -rf .fvm
```